# Is row-mt allowed in all formats in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I saw that FFmpeg added support for row based multi threading in version 3.4.  Since it is up to version 5+ now.  I have a question, if I am converting a series of different version files, can I add `-row-mt 1` to all my ffmpeg commands to make them multi thread, or will this error out.

I guess inotherwords, is this a specific encoding feature, or global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row-mt` is specific to `libvpx-vp9` and `libaom-av1` video encoders.

Answer (score 0):

Seems after trying some, i get a warning, but not an error

```
Codec AVOption row-mt (Enable row based multi-threading) specified for output file #0 (stuff1.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
```

So I guess it is stream specific only